# How to disable Dark Mode for my app in Mojave?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave, macos-darkmode

When I build my macOS app in Xcode 10 under Mojave, it automatically makes my app adopt Dark Mode. I am not ready yet to implement Dark Mode for my app.

How do I disable Dark Mode for my app, so it appears aqua in both the light and dark mode under macOS?

Answer (score 14):

From [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface: Choosing a Specific Appearance for Your App – Opt Out of Dark Mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_app#2993818):

> Apps linked against macOS 10.14 or later should support both light and
>   dark appearances. […]
>
> If you need extra time to work on your app's Dark Mode support, you
>   can temporarily opt out by including the
>   `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` key (with a value of `YES`) in your app’s
>   `Info.plist` file. Setting this key to `YES` causes the system to ignore
>   the user's preference and always apply a light appearance to your app.

Comment: Awesome, perfect answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (@available(macOS 10.14, *))
{
    NSApp.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed: NSAppearanceNameAqua];
}
```

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsappearancecustomization/choosing_a_specific_appearance_for_your_app).